# webpage is looking good on desktop but not on my smarthphone

Tags: html, css, css-grid

i was making a calculator with html and css only.
calculator was working fine but not looking good on my smartphone.

i think there is problem in the column spacing or the grid view.

How to get it to look similar on both android and desktop?

the css and html code given below.

```css
.calculator{
    position: relative;
    display: grid;
}

.calculator .value{
    grid-column: span 4;
    width:auto;
    height: 100px;
    text-align: right;
    border: none;
    outline:none;
    padding:10px;
    font-size:18px;
}
.calculator span{
    display: grid;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    color: #fff;
    background:#0c2835;
    /*place-items:center;*/
    border:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.1);

}

.calculator span:active{
    background:#74ff3b;
    color:#111;

}

.calculator span.clear{
    grid-column: span 2;
    width: auto;
    background:#ff3070;
}

.calculator span.plus{
grid-row: span 2;
height: 120px;  
}

.calculator span.equal{
    background:#03b1ff;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px){
[class*="calculator"] {
  width: auto%;
}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Calculator app</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<form class="calculator" name="calc">
<input class="value" type="text" name=txt readonly="">
<span class="num clear" onclick="document.calc.txt.value=''">c</span>
<span class="num" onclick="document.calc.txt.value+='/'">/</span>
<span class="num" onclick="document.calc.txt.value+='*'">*</span>
<span class="num" onclick="document.calc.txt.value+='7'">7</span>
<span class="num" onclick="document.calc.txt.value+='8'">8</span>
<span class="num" onclick="document.calc.txt.value+='9'">9</span>
<span class="num" onclick="document.calc.txt.value+='-'">-</span>
<span class="num" onclick="document.calc.txt.value+='4'">4</span>
<span class="num" onclick="document.calc.txt.value+='5'">5</span>
<span class="num" onclick="document.calc.txt.value+='6'">6</span>
<span class="num plus" onclick="document.calc.txt.value+='+'">+</span>
<span class="num" onclick="document.calc.txt.value+='3'">3</span>
<span class="num" onclick="document.calc.txt.value+='2'">2</span>
<span class="num" onclick="document.calc.txt.value+='1'">1</span>
<span class="num" onclick="document.calc.txt.value+='0'">0</span>
<span class="num" onclick="document.calc.txt.value+='00'">00</span>
<span class="num" onclick="document.calc.txt.value+='.'">.</span>
<span class="num equal" onclick="document.calc.txt.value=eval(calc.txt.value)">=</span>


</body>
</html>
```

it is looking like the given below screenshot in my smartphone.
how can i make it look like the desktop version of this webpage.

[image: this is the screenshot of webpage in my smartphone. i want to make it look like desktop webpage..]

Comment: hey Eric i set the div around my form and set max-width to 600px but still it is looking even more worse now... the first two colums are not even visible now in the smartphone ......  how to make it look like side by side buttons just like the desktop version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed your code for you I stopped setting other values/customizing so you can set it how you like it but it works now test on chrome and iphone.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
.calculator{
    position: relative;
    display: grid;
}

.calculator .value{
    grid-column: span 4;
    width:auto;
    height: 130px;
    text-align: right;
    border: none;
    outline:none;
    padding:10px;
    font-size:45px;
}
.calculator span{
    display: grid;
    color: #fff;
    background: #0c2835;
    font-size: 45px;
    padding: 20%;
    place-items: center;
    border: 5px solid rgba(0,0,0,.1);

}
.calculator span.dzero{
    padding: 0%;
}

.calculator span:active{
    background:#74ff3b;
    color:#111;

}
.calculator span.clear{
    grid-column: span 2;
    width: auto;
    background:#ff3070;
}
.calculator span.plus{
grid-row: span 2;
height: 100%;  
}
.calculator span.equal{
    background:#03b1ff;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px){
    [class*="calculator"] 
    { width: 100%;}
    }   
</style>
<head>
    <title>Calculator app</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div style="max-width: 600px;">
<form class="calculator" name="calc">
<input class="value" type="text" name="txt" readonly="">
<span class="num clear" onclick="document.calc.txt.value=''">c</span>
<span class="num" onclick="document.calc.txt.value+='/'">/</span>
<span class="num" onclick="document.calc.txt.value+='*'">*</span>
<span class="num" onclick="document.calc.txt.value+='7'">7</span>
<span class="num" onclick="document.calc.txt.value+='8'">8</span>
<span class="num" onclick="document.calc.txt.value+='9'">9</span>
<span class="num" onclick="document.calc.txt.value+='-'">-</span>
<span class="num" onclick="document.calc.txt.value+='4'">4</span>
<span class="num" onclick="document.calc.txt.value+='5'">5</span>
<span class="num" onclick="document.calc.txt.value+='6'">6</span>
<span class="num plus" onclick="document.calc.txt.value+='+'">+</span>
<span class="num" onclick="document.calc.txt.value+='3'">3</span>
<span class="num" onclick="document.calc.txt.value+='2'">2</span>
<span class="num" onclick="document.calc.txt.value+='1'">1</span>
<span class="num" onclick="document.calc.txt.value+='0'">0</span>
<span class="num dzero" onclick="document.calc.txt.value+='00'">00</span>
<span class="num" onclick="document.calc.txt.value+='.'">.</span>
<span class="num equal" onclick="document.calc.txt.value=eval(calc.txt.value)">=</span>
    </form>
</div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: hey Eric i set the div around my form and set the max width to 600px but still it is looking even more worse in the smartphone...

Comment: I will go through and optimize your code give me a day or two my project has hit a stand still atm so sit tight and ill have an optimized solution for you.

Comment: I would suggest you get rid of the 00 it screws up the format of the padding but that's up to you man hope that helped.

Comment: Hey Eric whenever you get time just take a look at my code.. and try to optimize it so it looks similar on both desktop and smartphone

Comment: I did look at the latest comment

Comment: use the code in my edited answer also selecting it as an answer would be nice!

Comment: Hey Eric You are amazing man.. Thanx a lot for helping me out....

Comment: could you explain me this code : @media only screen and (max-width: 600px){
    [class*="calculator"] 
    { width: 100%;}
    }

Comment: it makes the calculator fill the screen on mobile

Comment: so if i  am making  large websites will this code be suitable for mobile friendly version of the website..

Comment: im trying to increase my rating if you can vote it as the answer id appreciate it.

Comment: ohh sorry Eric i forgot to upvote your answer..  i will do it now..